# how to work with two @dp.message_handler()

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

I make a ChatGPT bot in telegram, everything works fine. I decided to add the /image command, by which the user first select the size, quantity and then a request to the image, and Dall'e will generate an image.

I made the command, but the problem is that they don't want to work with chatgpt at the same time. I made variables so that gpt_answer does not respond to the message until /image completes, but it did not work out here is the code:

```py
@dp.message_handler()
async def gpt_answer(message: types.Message):
    global is_image_processing
    if message.text.startswith('/image'):
        await images(message)
        return
    if not is_image_processing:
        #the rest of the code has no errors in it

#image
@dp.message_handler(commands=['image'])
async def images(message: types.Message):
    is_image_processing = True
    image_zapiska()
    zapiska()
    ins1 = InlineKeyboardButton('256x256', callback_data='size_256x256')
    ins2 = InlineKeyboardButton('512x512', callback_data='size_512x512')
    ins3 = InlineKeyboardButton('1024x1024', callback_data='size_1024x1024')
    keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(ins1, ins2, ins3)
    await message.reply("Выберите размеры изображения:", reply_markup=keyboard)

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data.startswith('size_'))
async def process_callback_size(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    size = callback_query.data.split('_')[1]
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
    inn1 = InlineKeyboardButton('1', callback_data='num_1')
    inn2 = InlineKeyboardButton('2', callback_data='num_2')
    inn3 = InlineKeyboardButton('3', callback_data='num_3')
    inn4 = InlineKeyboardButton('4', callback_data='num_4')
    keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(inn1, inn2, inn3, inn4)
    await bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=callback_query.message.chat.id, message_id=callback_query.message.message_id, text=f'Размер изображения: {size}\nВыберите количество изображений:', reply_markup=keyboard)

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data.startswith('num_'))
async def process_callback_num(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    global is_image_processing
    count = callback_query.data.split('_')[1]
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
    # Добавляем обработку выбранного количества изображений
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=callback_query.message.chat.id, text=f'Выбрано количество изображений: {count} \nвведите запрос:')
    is_image_processing = True

@dp.message_handler()
async def process_user_input(message: types.Message):
    global is_image_processing
    if is_image_processing:
        # Обработка запроса пользователя
        promt = message.text
        print(promt)
        is_image_processing = False
        return
    else:
        print(is_image_processing)
        return
```